# Add attribute called VenueName in LECTURE table for 3 possible venues

Tags: sql, oracle

Give the SQL to add the attribute VenueName to LECTURE. There are three possible venues:

Building A, Building B and Building C, which should be enforced by the SQL definition.

```
ALTER TABLE LECTURE
ADD VenueName VARCHAR2(100) NULL
INSERT INTO LECTURE (VenueName)
VALUES('Building A','Building B','Building C');
```

Following error shows:

> Error starting at line : 36 in command -
>   ALTER TABLE LECTURE 
>   ADD VenueName VARCHAR2(100) NULL
>   INSERT INTO LECTURE (VenueName)
>   VALUES('Building A','Building B','Building C')
>   Error report -
>   ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
>   01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: You're going to want to Google `SQL table constraints`, and possibly, depending on what database product you're using `sql data type enum`, which you should understand, and then avoid using in practice.

Comment: ALTER TABLE LECTURE
ADD VenueName ENUM('Building A','Building B','Building C');

shows following error --
Error starting at line : 36 in command -
ALTER TABLE LECTURE
ADD VenueName ENUM('Building A','Building B','Building C')
Error report -
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @EricBrandt Oracle doesn't have an `ENUM` data type so you sent the OP on a wild goose chase there.

Comment: @Sentinel, I didn't notice the Oracle error code at first blush, and there's not a tag. In fairness, it was a conditional recommendation.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yeah it took me a bit to notice that as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your SQL, first it should be two statements, separated by a semicolon (;) The first statement being the `ALTER TABLE` DDL statement, and the second being the `INSERT` DML statement.  After you fix that your DDL statement looks fine, though it won't enforce the limits specified.  To do that you either need to add an inline check constraint, an out of line check constraint, or a lookup table with a referential integrity constraint.

Finally your `INSERT` statement as formulated will not work in Oracle unless you are inserting into a table with three columns.  If you really want to insert the data somewhere as lookup data, then the last option I mentioned above is the way to go, you'll need to create the lookup table, insert the rows, and create the referential integrity constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Store venue names in a separate table and enforce referential constraints when adding the column to lectures

Demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c4728/10)